# draw a dynamic ellipse in panel

Tags: c#, .net

I just want to draw an ellipse dynamically when running . mouseclick then mousemove and then mouse release that's it . But, confused of detecting point(x,y).Can someone help me out of this

Comment: Which UI framework are you using? WPF? WinForms (GDI)?

Comment: If this is WinForms, you're looking for [`e.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.location.aspx).

Comment: Sorry friends , sterday couldn't possible to reply early

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just need to record the starting point from the MouseDown event, so that you can make the ellipse with the point recorded from the MouseUp event.

Simple demo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

  private Point _StartPoint;
  private List<Rectangle> _Ovals = new List<Rectangle>();

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseDown);
    this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseUp);
    this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
  }

  void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    foreach (Rectangle r in _Ovals)
      e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, r);
  }

  void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
      _StartPoint = e.Location;
  }

  void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
      _Ovals.Add(MakeRectangle(_StartPoint, e.Location));
      this.Invalidate();
    }
  }

  private Rectangle MakeRectangle(Point p1, Point p2) {
    int x = (p1.X < p2.X ? p1.X : p2.X);
    int y = (p1.Y < p2.Y ? p1.Y : p2.Y);
    int w = Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X);
    int h = Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y);
    return new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
  }
}
```